# How to update outer variable from within a for loop (Python, Jinja2)

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I'm runing a Python application on Google App Engine platform. Bu conditions, I have a term (for example 12 months), and in each month I make a specific payment (PAYMENT variable). Then I need to count all made payments and update a TOTAL_PAYMENT variable.

```
{% set total_payment = 0 %}

{% for month in range(0,term) %}

  {% payment = SOME_INT_VALUE %}
  {% total_payment = total_payment + payment%}

{% endfor%}
{{ total_payment }}
```

Instead of having a total payment value, I'm still getting a 0. What's the problem?

Comment: I think you should use `set` tag in `{% payment = SOME_INT_VALUE %}`. i.e. `{% set payment = SOME_INT_VALUE %}`.

Comment: @LeonYoung for some reason the variable resets its value outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit dirty, but it's works well.

```
{% set vars = {'total_payment': 0} %}

{% for month in range(0, term) %}
  {% if vars.update({'total_payment': vars.total_payment + SOME_INT_VALUE}) %}{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{{ vars.total_payment }}
```